# nginx-ingress config map snippets being ignored by the nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster, where I have deployed an nginx ingress controller using the [helm nginx-ingress chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress).

I need to add some custom config to the nginx.conf file that is generated in the nginx-controller-pod, and I am seeing an issue where if I add a one line option such as `proxy-buffer-size: "512k"` I can see this reflected in the nginx.conf file and everything works as expected.

However, if I attempt to add a snippet to accomplish the same thing:

```
location-snippet: |
  proxy_buffer_size "512k";
```

It is as though this is ignored by the nginx.conf file and the `proxy_buffer_size` setting remains at it's default value.

I need to be able to add `http-snippet`, `server-snippet` and `location-snippet` overrides but whether I try to add them to the ConfigMap or as an annotation in the Ingress.yaml file they are always ignored.

My Ingress yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true" 
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"    
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"

    ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet: |
       proxy_buffer_size 512k;     --This does not update the nginx.conf
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.app.co.uk
    secretName: tls-secret

  rules:
  - host: my.app.co.uk
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myappweb-service
          servicePort: 80
```

My nginx config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-0.28.3
    component: controller
    heritage: Tiller
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: default
data:
  proxy-buffer-size: "512k" -- this works and updates the nginx.conf

  location-snippet: |
    proxy_buffers 4 512k; -- this does not update the nginx.conf

  server-snippet: |       -- this does not update the nginx.conf
    location /messagehub {
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
```

Comment: Just want to share my answer here for Kubernetes v1.23 + Helm 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71087753/4992248

Comment: Just want to share here my answer for Kubernetes v1.23 + Helm 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71087753/4992248

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that my problem was due to the content of the snippet that I was applying. Every time you run `kubectl apply -f myconfigmap.yaml`, a validation is run against the changes that you are trying to apply to the nginx.conf. When this validation fails, it fails silently and there is nothing to alert you to this in the terminal.

In fact, you still get the `configmap/nginx-ingress-controller configured` message.

For example, when I add this to the config map, it updates the nginx.conf as expected:

```
http-snippet: |
  sendfile on;
```

However, when I add this, nothing changes:

```
http-snippet: |
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
```

The reason being that this has failed validation, but the only way to find that out is to look at the logs of the nginx ingress controller pod. In this instance I see:

```
Error: exit status 1
2018/10/16 07:45:49 [emerg] 470#470: "tcp_nopush" directive is duplicate in 
/tmp/nginx-cfg468835321:245
nginx: [emerg] "tcp_nopush" directive is duplicate in /tmp/nginx-cfg468835321:245
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg468835321 test failed
```

So I was duplicating a directive that already existed.

Answer (score 23):

I spent a day untill got that for **ingress-nginx** (from Kubernetes) there are `*-snippet`, but for **nginx-ingress** (from NGINX) that `*-snippets` with **s**.

Look here:

- ingress-nginx: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#main-snippet
- nginx-ingress: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/#snippets-and-custom-templates

Comment: thanks man I was also doing the same, it saves my day !!!!

Answer (score 13):

If you'd like to modify your Kubernetes `Ingress` the annotation options are these:

- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` for an nginx location block snippet
- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` for a snippet in the nginx config service block

Looks like you are using `nginx.org/location-snippets:` for that case.

There's also a YAML invalid syntax on nginx config example and also you should use plurals as in `server-snippets` according to this [example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/3f0740d182a9f46cfc83ef085d9721cb102c97b9/examples/customization/nginx-config.yaml#L43). There's a typo in the [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#server-snippet) as of this writing. Opened [this ticket](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/397) to follow up.

It should be something like this:

```
  server-snippets: |
    location /messagehub {
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
```

instead of this:

```
  server-snippet: |
    location /messagehub {
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Notice the indentation of the last curly brace.

Comment: Thank you @Rico, good spot on the brace indentation. However, if I just run the apply with only the  `location-snippet` line in the yaml file this is also ignored, and this does not include any braces

Comment: I updated the answer, looks like you need to use `location-snippets` and there's typo in the docs

Comment: Thanks @Rico, I have updated my yaml with the server snippet in your example but do not see it reflected in the generated nginx.conf

Comment: Did you restart your ingress controller? I believe you need to restart it after you change the ConfigMap

Answer (score 0):

If some needs solution for Kubernetes 1.23 and Helm 3, [here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71087753/4992248) in the similar topic.