# Increase URL length limit for K8S ingress

Tags: http, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a GET request URL into a service on my kubernetes that's ~9k long and it seems like the request is getting stuck in Kubernetes's ingress. When I tried calling the url from within the docker or from other docker in the cluster it works fine. However when I go through a domain name I'm getting the following response header:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think the parameter you must modify is **Client Body Buffer Size**

> Sets buffer size for reading client request body per location. In case
>   the request body is larger than the buffer, the whole body or only its
>   part is written to a temporary file.  By default, buffer size is equal
>   to two memory pages.  This is 8K on x86, other 32-bit platforms, and
>   x86-64. It is usually 16K on other 64-bit platforms. This annotation
>   is applied to each location provided in the ingress rule

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: "1000" # 1000 bytes
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 1k # 1 kilobyte
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 1K # 1 kilobyte
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 1m # 1 megabyte
```

So you must add an [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#client-body-buffer-size) to your nginx ingress config.

Comment: We ran into a similar issue and this did not help. Event with increasing the buffer sizes using nginx-configmap did not work.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to set `http2_max_header_size` and `http2_max_field_size` in my ingress server-snippet annotation. For example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        http2_max_header_size 16k;
        http2_max_field_size 16k;
```

I was getting ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED and ERR_FAILED in Google Chrome and "empty response" using curl, but the backend would work if accessed directly from the cluster network.

Assigning `client-header-buffer-size` or `large-client-header-buffers` in the ingress controller ConfigMap didn't seem to work for me either, but I realized that curl would do it if using HTTP 1.1 (`curl --http1.1`)

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the **configmap name** in the nginx ingress controller pod describition

```
kubectl -n utility describe pods/test-nginx-ingress-controller-584dd58494-d8fqr |grep configmap
      --configmap=test-namespace/test-nginx-ingress-controller
```

**Note**: In my case, the namespace is "test-namespace" and the configmap name is "test-nginx-ingress-controller"

2. Create a **configmap yaml**

```
cat  << EOF > test-nginx-ingress-controller-configmap.yaml

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: test-namespace
data:
  large-client-header-buffers: "4 16k"
EOF
```

**Note**: Please replace the **namespace** and **configmap name** as per finding in the **step 1**

3. **Deploy** the configmap yaml

```
kubectl apply -f test-nginx-ingress-controller-configmap.yaml
```

Then you will see the change is updated to nginx controller pod after mins

```
i.g.
kubectl -n test-namespace exec -it test-nginx-ingress-controller-584dd58494-d8fqr -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf|grep large
    large_client_header_buffers     4 16k;
```

Thanks to the sharing by **NeverEndingQueue** in [How to use ConfigMap configuration with Helm NginX Ingress controller - Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884735/how-to-use-configmap-configuration-with-helm-nginx-ingress-controller-kubernet/68733592#68733592)