# How to enable http/2 support in nginx-ingress with EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I have configured a cluster on EKS and installed nginx-ingress. Using our ingress rule it works, but I don't know how to make it work with HTTP/2? and I am using ELB for loadbalancer. Is there way to enable http/2 with my stack?

Comment: Did you try [setting up](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-configuration/) [`use-http2` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-http2)?

Comment: what annotation for this? Could you help me?

Comment: Please create ConfigMap and under `data:`, set `use-http2: "true"`, then apply. Similar steps how to do it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884735/how-to-use-configmap-configuration-with-helm-nginx-ingress-controller-kubernet/68733592#68733592). Also, please double check if you setup your AWS ELB with proper ["Protocol Version"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-group-protocol-version).

Comment: Hi @Ted Hoang, please let me know if you tried above steps. Which ["Protocol Version"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-group-protocol-version) AWS ELB are you using?